# arrange number and text in acscending order in MS access table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have table with varchar field which has number value and string value. I cant convert to modify this varchar to number in the table structure, since we have string values also.

In my form i directly fetch data from the table.  I have a problem that this numeric value column is not getting sorted properly.

I supposed to get my ouput as 100 101 1000 1001 A123 B234

but wat i get in my form is as follows 100 1000 10001 101 A123 B234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you base your form on a query, you can create a sort field on the fly to get what you need. In this simplistic example, Table1 has a field "ID" with your sample data. This query will give you the desired sort:

```
SELECT Table1.ID
FROM Table1
ORDER BY IIf(IsNumeric([ID]),Right$("00000" & [ID],5),[ID]);
```

Comment: BTW: This answer works by "converting a number to text" rather than the question's title "convert text to a number", and it is done in a query, leaving the table structure unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for ur relply Rachel. This query is workinf fine with my table.. But my table is called directly in form. if i give this order condition in the data tab of id its not sorting the data. Please guide me

Comment: You should be able to change the source of the form to be a query. Build a query that brings in all the fields from your table, but is sorted like the example above.